# How to protect Firebase application from infinite loops?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, firebase-security

Currently building a simple chat app where everyone can actually login and have a chat with anyone. How to prevent someone from creating a for loop that sends message infinitely or many times?

Comment: how to prevent spam you ask. It's probably beyond the scope of firebase.  Perhaps you could setup a security rule preventing saving a message if the previous x messages are from the same user.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Firebase rate limiting in security rules?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24830079/firebase-rate-limiting-in-security-rules)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're looking for rate-limiting with Firebase, check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/24841859/879295 for a comprehensive answer by @kato.