# Is it possible to run code from Firebase Storage Security rules to delete files after 24hours

Tags: firebase, firebase-security, firebase-storage

If I were to build a snapchat equivalent mobile app, how could I use the Firebase Storage security rules to delete an image after 24 hours?

I didn't think it was possible but it was briefly mentioned by a Firebase employee in this [Firebase video](https://youtu.be/PUBnlbjZFAI)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to automatically delete files (or perform any other action) from your security rules. What you *can* do is make the files (or node in the database) inaccessible after a certain time.

See this answer for an example of this: [Firebase security rule to prevent customers from circumventing usage tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26520793/firebase-security-rule-to-prevent-customers-from-circumventing-usage-tracking/26595914#26595914)

There's a good example of this in the [Firebase Storage reference documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/storage/#timestamp):

```
allow read: if request.time < resource.createdAt + duration.value(1, "h");
```

Hat tip to Mike McDonald for pointing that one out. :-)

Comment: @puf thanks. can I run a script on my own server to delete files in firebase storage after 24 hours?

Comment: Certainly. You'll want to use the gcloud SDKs for that, since Firebase doesn't come with its own server-side SDKs.