# Receive callback (Backend) on validate fail

Tags: firebase

I'm serching for a solution for a backend and firebase same interesting, but I have some questions before starting to using it.

My question is related to this post (you don't need to read it) [Firebase rate limiting in security rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24830079/firebase-rate-limiting-in-security-rules/24841859#24841859)

The question was how to be sur the client can do the same request more than 1 time every 5 seconds. The anwser is fine. My question is:

If we assume the client app has no bug and it check if there is no more than 1 request every 5 seconds, the only way we can fail the "validate" is if someone is trying to hack (sending request without using the client app). Is there a way to send a callback to a admin user or to write something in the database to tell someone is trying to write faster than expected and the user is maybe a hacker?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Security rule failures are not accessible through an API at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Look firebase is working on a new feature that will allow me to do that

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/

"With Cloud Functions database event handling, you can modify the Realtime Database in response to user behavior, keeping the system up to date and clean."