# Firebase security rules traversing through the database for validation

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security, angularfire2

I am having an issue when trying the following validation rule:

```
            ".validate": "newData.val() >= now - 2000 && newData.val() >= data.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().child('users/'+auth.uid+'/lastPostAt').val() - 2000"
```

Here are the relevant area's of my Firebase database schema:

```
areas
    -> area1
        -> posts
            -> uid
                 -> post object ( has timestamp property (date) - firebase timestamp)


user
    -> uid
         -> user object ( has timestamp property (lastPostAt) - Firebase timestamp)
```

When a post is submitted it updates the `lastPostAt` timestamp property in the user object for the specific user that submitted the post.

What I am looking for is some Firebase rules to ensure that when a new post is submitted that it is not stored unless the user has not submitted another post within the last 2 minutes.

I have look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24830079/firebase-rate-limiting-in-security-rules) on StackOverflow, but I am trying to see if it is possible to do this with my implementation.

Under the `$uid` for my posts node, I am trying a `.validate` rule:

```
        "posts" : {
           "$message_id": {
                ".indexOn": "username",
                ".write": "newData.hasChildren(['date'])",
                "date" : {
                    ".validate": "newData.val() >= now - 2000 && newData.val() >= data.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().child('users/'+auth.uid+'/lastPostAt').val() - 2000"
            }
```

Currently, when I submit a post, both the timestamps are the same, but I can keep posting more and more posts with no delay.

Comment: Why did you delete [your previous post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41124660/firebase-rules-to-prevent-spam) and add a new one? If you have details to add, please add them to your original question next time.

Comment: You can use `root.child('users/'+auth.uid+'/lastPostAt')` instead of `data.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().child('users/'+auth.uid+'/lastPostAt')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to prevent additional posts for two minutes, `newData.val()` needs to be at least 120,000 milliseconds *greater* than `lastPostAt`.

So your rule should be:

```
"date" : {
    ".validate": "newData.val() >= now - 2000 && newData.val() >= data.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().child('users/'+auth.uid+'/lastPostAt').val() + 120000"
}
```

Also, if you are using [`ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ServerValue.html#TIMESTAMP), you can use:

```
newData.val() === now
```

Using this in the rule would prevent arbitrary, future timestamps from being used. (And if you are not using `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`, you should consider using it.)