# Firebase Database Rules - Restrict number of Calls in an hour?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",
    ".write": "false"
  }
}
```

We have firebase application where user is authenticated via AuthID. We are using REST API to get access to database. Is it possible to restrict number of reads in an hour for a user? Want to implement this in read rules

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null" && **??????**,
    ".write": "false"
  }
}
```

Comment: There is no built-in rate limiting. But you can build it yourself as Kato shows here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24830079/firebase-rate-limiting-in-security-rules

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - Thanks for your reply. I have seen the post .. however I don't store any previous reference.. i only have GET REST API with access_token... is it possible without updating any data in previous request?