# How to limit the number queries a user can send in firebase

Tags: firebase

Is it possible to limit the number of queries a user can make in one day (server side)?
I would like to add a filter that checks:
if number_of_queries_user_made_this_day < CONST_NUMBER:
     proceed
else:
    return http error: "over the limit"

thanks.

Comment: There's nothing built in, but if you're willing you can build something in security rules. For the Firebase Realtime Database, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24830079/firebase-rate-limiting-in-security-rules

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in rate limiting for either Realtime Database or Firestore.  You would have to control access through some other middleware or backend you control using code you've written.