# How to limit rate of data reads from Firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I would like to limit the rate of data reads per user from the Realtime Database. There are good ways to limit writes like described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24830079/firebase-rate-limiting-in-security-rules) but I can't find any solution on how to limit data reads.

Can this be done with Security Rules, Cloud Functions or can I limit it somewhere in the Firebase account? I have checked the documentation but can't find the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This applies to both Realtime Database and Firestore, except with different terminology.  (Location == document)

You won't be able to do this without also writing some value at a location in the database every time a read is performed.  You can't write a location in a security rule, and you can't force the client to write at the same time as a read.

Even if you were able to write a location in a rule to use in a rate limit, you would then have to read that location for every read that must be limited, and that kind of defeats the purpose of a rate limit (since they could continue to try to read a restricted location in a way that just causes more reads to happen).

Comment: Thanks for information. Is there a way to limit read operations per second per user with quotas like in the Google Cloud Platform?

Comment: No, you can't.  You can file a feature request, though.  http://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features

Comment: @DougStevenson So using Firebase (RTDB or Firestore) means anyone will be able to hack your app to explode your reads and potentially make you go bankrupt? That must be wrong.

Comment: No support for rate limits is truly crazy. I just filed a feature request here:  https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/features/ . I would suggest you do the same so this can be taken care of.