# Does Firebase App Check mitigate billing attacks on the web with Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-app-check, recaptcha-enterprise

It's been a topic of conversation for years now regarding the potential for billing attacks if you allow reads and / or writes on the client-side Firestore. Somewhat recently, Firebase introduced [App Check](https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check) which adds extra layers of security.

I believe I understand how this could mitigate billing attacks within an iOS or Android app: any request to Firestore must be coming from the final built app itself. However, I'm more unclear how this could be helpful on the web side, which uses [reCAPTCHA Enterprise](https://cloud.google.com/security/products/recaptcha-enterprise). If I understand the flow correctly of reCAPTCHA enterprise, a user would obtain a token which has a risk score attached to it and the frontend client itself determines if it's okay to take on that risk or not.

My question is: couldn't you still have someone obtain a token by valid means, and include it within a browser console script which spams reads? For instance, something like the attach mentioned [here](https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/Fuvnk5mPoSU?pli=1):

```
while(true) { db.collection("posts").forEach(post => console.log(post)) }
```

If reCAPTCHA Enterprise is not the answer for securing reads, is there any way to rate-limit reads or any other security features I'm not thinking of?

I understand that GCP / Firebase have historically been good at addressing if there have been malicious activity within accounts, and you can set up billing limits, but I want to be sure and clear on the above. Thanks!

Examples of other posts with similar concerns, before App Check:

- [Add a limit for data reads firebase firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59368783/add-a-limit-for-data-reads-firebase-firestore)
- [How to limit rate of data reads from Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54508235/how-to-limit-rate-of-data-reads-from-firebase)
- https://groups.google.com/g/firebase-talk/c/Fuvnk5mPoSU?pli=1